# Speech to text to microphone

Tags: text-mining, speech-to-text

Is it possible to use an artificial intelligence voice as a microphone in real time? I would like something where I could speak and it would be spoken by an AI, such as Cortana's voice, and pass it to my microphone so that I could speak on discord or teamspeak for example. Is there a solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of solutions available : https://www.google.com/search?q=voice+transformer+online&oq=voice+transform&aqs=chrome.1.0i512l2j69i57j0i512l7.12751j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8